# How to solve this error "Could not load file or assembely 'System.Dynamic' or one of its dependencies"

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, ddl

I am working on a .Net project 3.5 frame work (Sharepoint server)

My project is working fine but when I deployed the wsp of the following solution in another machine having same configuration and 3.5 .NET Framework and all similar setting to that of my machine I am getting this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Dynamic' or one of its
>   dependencies

I have added all the DLLs which is in my project. whereas the same code /project is running well and good in my machine.

How can I add this in my project?

Comment: I think it is Target Framework conflict.

Comment: both target 3.5 .Net framework
then where is the conflict

Comment: `System.Dynamic.dll` is part of .NET 4, to start with. You may be able to install the `Dynamic Language Runtime version for .NET 3.5`, but you certainly won't be able to use the dynamic feature from `C# 4`.

Comment: actually the full error is
 “Could not load file or assembely 'System.Dynamic' or one of its dependencies . This assembely is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded"

Comment: As told above. It is clear that you are using `System.Dynamic.dll` which is newer.

Comment: but in my entire project i have never used this System.Dynamic.dll
then how come it is showing that ...

Comment: Answer provided on your duplicate post :). Try that

Comment: But my problem is not resolved :(

Comment: its also saying one of its dependencies.  What can be the depndencies or dll related to this

Comment: can anybody help ?
its past 5 days , still i am not done with this issue ?
I have tried everything installed the .net 4.0 framework
still no solution...
anybody help please...

Answer (score -2):

You should clear the temporary files, then build and run.

```
C:\Users\[SystemName]\AppData\Local\Temp\ASP.NET
```

Comment: Sorry, it did for me, thats why i suggested to you also

Comment: can anybody help ?
its past 5 days , still i am not done with this issue ?
I have tried everything installed the .net 4.0 framework
still no solution...
anybody help please...