# Could not load file or assembely 'System.Dynamic' or one of its dependencies . This assembely is built by a runtime newer than the

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint-2010, asp.net-3.5

My project is working fine but when I deployed the wsp of the following solution in another machine(server) having same configuration and 3.5 .NET Framework and all similar setting to that of my machine I am getting this error:

> “Could not load file or assembely 'System.Dynamic' or one of its
>   dependencies . This assembely is built by a runtime newer than the
>   currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded"

I have added all the DLLs which is in my project where as the same code /project is running well and good in my machine

How can I add this in my project?

Comment: you don't need to repeat question. If you want to change the title or contents of question use `edit` link. [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421316/how-to-solve-this-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembely-system-dynamic-or-on)

Comment: can anybody help ?
its past 5 days , still i am not done with this issue ?
I have tried everything installed the .net 4.0 framework
still no solution...
anybody help please...

Comment: Trying again to put on hold as a dup....

Answer (score 0):

You have this question tagged as [asp.net-3.5](/questions/tagged/asp.net-3.5) however [`System.Dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a .NET 4.0 feature. You need to install 4.0 on the IIS server and [configure IIS to use the 4.0 CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890245/how-to-add-asp-net-4-0-as-application-pool-on-iis-7-windows-7).

Comment: As i have said i have deleloped the prjct in 3.5 .net framework.. and same deployed in another server having same 3.5 .net framework
then why its showing this error..........

Comment: its also saying one of its dependencies.  What can be the depndencies or dll related to this ?